# Remove HTML element completely just by using CSS?

Tags: html, css, element

Just like `removeAttribute` in JavaScript, after which the element won't be visible in the source.

Comment: you can use `display:none`

Comment: CSS is for styling - not for direct DOM manipulation. If `display: none` doesn't do what you are trying to do, then it is not possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot remove an element from the DOM tree using CSS. You can only prevent it from being rendered in the layout with `display: none`; doing so does not prevent it from responding to events or cause it to be ignored by CSS selectors such as `+` and `:nth-child()`. You won't be able to interact with an element that's not there so you wouldn't be able to trigger events the usual way, but its "essence" remains, so to speak.

Comment: Agreed, but note that in some circumstances, replaced content might be unloaded, actually making some elements unreachable to js anymore (but arguably they're not part of the *document tree* per se, even if reachable through DOM APIs.)

Comment: I had to downvote because events won't fire on a `display: none;` element. At least in many cases. If you correct me, I'll have no problem upvoting this answer.

Comment: @Cody: You're not wrong; intuitively an element that's not there can't be interacted with to fire events. The event handlers are still there and can still be called, at least programmatically. I think my answer could be worded better.

Comment: @BoltClock: you *are* right... you can still receive events dispatched on `display: none;` elements. I would have upvoted your response but SO has locked my action (I'm sorry). Here's a CodePen of proof you are correct: https://codepen.io/cScarlson/pen/zYPLvRw?editors=1111

Comment: @Cody: No problem, I added something to my answer.

Comment: Ah-ha! I was able to upvote your answer just now. I appreciate your attention on this.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible with CSS.
Even if you use `display:none`, the element will be still in DOM tree.

CSS is for styling not for DOM manipulation. Use JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: none;
```

'Unlike the visibility property, which leaves an element in normal document flow,display: none removes the element completely from the document. It does not take up any space, even though the HTML for it is still in the source code. This is because it is, indeed, removed from the document flow. For all intents and purposes, the item is gone. This can be a good thing or a bad thing, depending on what your intentions are. It can also be damaging to your page if you misuse this property!'

https://www.lifewire.com/display-none-vs-visibility-hidden-3466884

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: none` to hide an element but it will still be on the DOM.

You can also use `visibility: hidden` and it will also still be on the DOM but the DOM will reflect the same vertical flow even though the element is hidden. In other words if the element is a block, a block space will still be reserved for the hidden element. And with `display: none` the space will also be removed along with the element as it is hidden.

Unless you use JavaScript, with CSS you are only changing the visibility of a DOM element that is existent on the DOM. Which can absolutely serve your purpose depending on what you are trying to do.

If you need more help, just comment with more detail and I'd be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

With **CSS** you must change the attribute **display** to **none**.

And with **JavaScript** you must change de **id attribute** to another value that doesn't make sense to the application.

Answer (score -2):

You actually can. Not directly in CSS but in combination with Javascript/jQuery you could.

In HTML give a class of "removeFromDom" to the Elements you want to have removed.

```
<p class="removeFromDom">your text here</p>
```

In CSS you add these Lines to make it invisible, if JS is not working.

```
.removeFromDom { display:none !important; visibility:hidden !important; }
```

In a jQuery file, that you load on any site, create this function::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".removeFromDom").remove();
});
```

Et voila.. your jQuery file removes your Items from the DOM. I wouldn't recommend it for security reasons if there is a link nobody should be able to see anytime..

Comment: Good try, this actually works against the browser DevTool(F12) but not against the source.